# Como monto este select

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite
Como eu montaria este select
1 - entrando no site os anúncios premium ficam acima dos grátis e todos Rand -> OK mas eu preciso também.
Selecionando a cidade, somente os anúncios premium do estado/cidade aparecem e abaixo os gratuitos deste estado/cidade.
Como esta meu código:

```
SELECT * FROM estudio_ts ORDER BY estudio_premium DESC, rand()
```

este funciona corretamente

```
SELECT * FROM estudio_ts WHERE estudio_uf = '$uf' OR estudio_cidade LIKE '%$city%'  ORDER BY estudio_premium DESC, rand()
```

Este funciona mas coloca todos os premium acima, inclusive de outros estados/cidade

Comment: Sinceramente: não consegui entender o que deseja.

Comment: Order by (case when estudio_uf = '$uf' then 0 else 1 end),estudio_premium DESC, rand()

Comment: Não alterou nada na consulta.. 
mas mesmo assim muito obrigado

Comment: Anonimo o que eu preciso é:
Vou tentar explicar de outra forma...
Se tenho anúncios no brasil inteiro, quando o usuário entra no site, aparece todos os anúncios, sendo o pago vindo primeiro..
Mas quando o usuário entra no estado do Rio de Janeiro, por exemplo,,, Só deverá aparecer anúncios do Rio de Janeiro, vindo primeiro os anúncios pagos.. e não aparecendo anúncios pagos e não pagos de outros estados... Escrevendo este comentário eu tive uma ideia.. se funcionar eu posto a solução aqui.. Obg mesmo assim

Comment: Obrigado pessoal.. consegui resolver assim. Pode não ser o certo mas é o que eu consigo no momento..
o que precisava era.. usuário chega no site e aparece anúncios de todos os estados sendo os pagos primeiro e aleatórios..
Usuário seleciona estado ou cidade, apenas anúncios daquela região aparecerá sendo os pagos primeiro...

estou postando aqui por o site diz q não posso mais responder...

Comment: Bom.. o site aqui não deixa eu responder..por ter baixa reputação.. acho q é isso.. então vou ficar devendo a resolução